# Struggling to add active class/state to faq accordion

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I'm quite the amateur when it comes to Javascript, hence why I'm posting this on here. I've spent quite a lot of time searching for the answer but can't seem to find it.

I've created a FAQ Accordion on jsfiddle and can't for the life on me get it to add an active class/state when the tabs are extended so I can apply styling appropriately.

If anyone can be of any assistance it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
 $(function () {
    $('.acc_trigger a').click(function () {
        $('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').slideUp();
        $(this).closest('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').stop().slideDown();
        return false;
    })

    $('.expand').click(function () {
        $('.acc_trigger').closest('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').slideDown('slow');
        return false;
    })

    $('.collapse').click(function () {
        $('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').slideUp('slow');
        return false;
    })
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leegostelow/k3kzp9ks/)**

Answer (score 1):

What  yakutsa said, but to answer your question you can continue to use Jquery and use the `.addClass('addedClass')` to the end of whichever you wish to change.

For example if you want the opened container to have a red background

```
$('.acc_trigger').next('.acc_container').slideUp().addClass('addedClass');
```

width css

```
.addedClass {
    background: red;
}
```

when you close it, use `.removeClass('addedClass');`

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k3kzp9ks/2/)